# Преобразование подряд идущих пробелов в один в python

Tags: python

Ввожу этот код:

```
a = input()
for i in range (len(a)):
  if (ord(a[i])) == 32:
    while(ord(a[i + 1])) == 32:
      a = a[:i + 1] + a[i + 2:]
print(a)
```

Пишет: string index out of range

Comment: Вполне закономерное поведение на такой код, если вам не готовое а понять причину то: вот ```a = a[:i + 1] + a[i + 2:]``` в этой строке вы пытаетесь получить доступ к символам которых нет, когда подходите к чтению двух последних символов строки

Comment: а зачем такие сложности? `print(' '.join(a.split()))`

Comment: @АлексейР, результат `split` будет немного другим: пробелы по краям удалятся, переводы строки с табуляциями тоже. Скорее всего ТС такие тонкости не волнуют, но на всякий случай надо оговорить.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка потому что вы меняете строку во время обработки. Это можно поправить, но код будет сложным. Проще придерживаться правила о неизменности структуры контейнера в цикле `for`. Я хотел сказать - не нужно редактировать строку. Если простота кода вас не интересует, то добавлю что это ещё и очень не эффективно.

Если в сроке единственный пробел - последний символ, вы тоже обратитесь за конец строки. Если есть возможность не обращаться к строке по индексу, этого не надо делать. Индексация - низкоуровневое средство, требует аккуратности.

`prev_space` - флаг "предыдущий символ - пробел". Бежим по строке, символы накапливаем в списке. Обращений по индексам нет.

В конце список преобразуем в строку:

```
def join_spaces(s):
    result = []
    prev_space = False
    for c in s:
        space = c == ' '
        if not prev_space or not space:
            result.append(c)
        prev_space = space
    return ''.join(result)


print(join_spaces(input()))
```

Если в коде на Питоне есть накопление элементов в списке, обычно его можно заменить на генератор:

```
def join_spaces(s):
    prev_space = False
    for c in s:
        space = c == ' '
        if not prev_space or not space:
            yield c
        prev_space = space


print(''.join(join_spaces(input())))
```

Правильно решить задачу через регулярное выражение `' +'`. Оно соответствует любому числу пробелов подряд. [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) заменит его на одиночный пробел:

```
import re


def join_spaces(s):
    return re.sub(' +', ' ', s)


print(join_spaces(input()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, самый простой для понимания

```
a = input()
while "  " in a:
    a= a.replace("  ", " ")
print(a)
```

А так в комментариях ответили почему:

> Вполне закономерное поведение на такой код, если вам не готовое а понять причину то: вот a = a[:i + 1] + a[i + 2:] в этой строке вы пытаетесь получить доступ к символам которых нет, когда подходите к чтению двух последних символов строки

Исправить именно ваш код можно добавив дополнительное условие или))) сделать так(это если что шутка):

```
a = input()
try:
    for i in range (len(a)):
        if (ord(a[i])) == 32:
            while(ord(a[i+1])) == 32:
                a = a[:i + 1] + a[i + 2:]
except:
    print(a)
```

Comment: Не нужно шутить с кодом. Многие не читают толком комментарии, а копипастят не глядя код из ответов )